# In what situations does Flash / SWF misbehave in different browsers?

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, browser, flash

Recently I had some issues with Flash in IE, involving a SWF which is something like a gallery.

In Firefox its loads perfectly, but in IE it doesn't work properly sometimes. The first time it is loaded its works fine but when I refresh all the images are blank.  The image data came from XML.

I wish to get some tips regarding the browsers and Flash / SWF behavior in each.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you loading your images externally (i.e., not embedding them in the movie)?

Comment: When loads fail in one browser, in my experience it tends to be something delicate about how the loads are made or received on the server side. Flash doesn't keep its own network stack, it passes requests to the browser, so if there's a content bug that depends on, for example, the timing or order of the calls, it can work out differently in different browsers.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample webpage that embeds the SWF and manifests your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I once faced a similar problem. IE first displays image properly. Upon refresh it didn't display the image. The problem was with the IE security settings on scripting languages. If the script fails to load properly on first time, IE blacklists the script and hence blocks it from running again. When u reset the security settings it will work. But you should still get into the bottomline of the issue and fix it.

Thanks,
Nirmal

Comment: @nirmal: How can i enable security on flash action script 2.0